# How do I correctly add a workspace framework to an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I add a framework from a different project in my workspace, I inevitably end up with something like this in my `pbxproj`:

```
path = "../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-asdfasdfadsfasdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bar.framework"; sourceTree = "<group>"
```

Okay, so I go change the location to "Built Products" (`BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`) in the file inspector. The goal should be no `path`, just `name = Bar.framework`. *Sometimes*, this works. Other times, I end up with a different garbage relative path, and can only fix the problem by opening the `pbxproj` in a text editor.

What's the variable here? How do I make this just work, 100% of the time?

I'm using Xcode 7.3, but I can't remember an Xcode version post-workspaces that this wasn't an issue in.